# In PHP Slim framework a specific route can't end in 's' or it throws a 500 server error

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to create a get route with PHP Slim framework.

```
<?php 
$app->get('/bands', function() {
    $response["test"] = 'tester';
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

Whenever I call this route I get a 500 Server Error and my PHP log states that `$app` is null. However if I change the route to:

```
<?php 
$app->get('/band', function() {
    $response["test"] = 'tester';
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

Everything works as it should. There is something about the 's' in the bands route. I just can't put an 's' on band to make it bands.

UPDATE: None of the routes with an 's' on the end work!

I just don't understand why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you wonder what `echoResponse(200,$response);` does, it justs takes the array and returns it to the browser as a JSON object with the HTTP response 200 Success. This it what it looks like:

```
function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);

    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Here's my index.php:

```
<?php
require 'libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// The separate files that serve the routes
require_once 'bands.php';
require_once 'users.php';
require_once 'instructors.php';
require_once 'musicians.php';

function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);

    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}

$app->run();
```

Then my routes included in the above required files:

Bands:

```
<?php 
$app->get('/bands', function() {
    $response["test"] = 'tester';
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

Users:

```
<?php 
$app->get('/users', function() {
    $response["test"] = 'tester';
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

Musicians:

```
<?php 
$app->get('/musicians', function() {
    $response["test"] = 'tester';
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

Instructors:

```
<?php 
$app->get('/instructors', function() {
    $response["test"] = 'tester';
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

All of the above routes work if i remove the trailing 's'.

If it helps. Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Which version of Slim?

Comment: I'm using Slim 2.3.5

Comment: What's your `echoResponse` function, can we see it?  Any other routes?

Comment: Have you a folder called bands?

Comment: No, I do not have a folder called 'bands' all the PHP files for my API is in the 'api' folder. The routes work with the location of my PHP files. Just not with the 's'. The ```echoResponse()``` function works properly but I'll show it anyway. I'll update the question with the function.

Comment: Have you any other route patterns that could match '/bands'?

Comment: No, I'll add all my routes in the question. All routes work unless you throw an 's' on the end (i.e. 'band' to 'bands' or 'user' to 'users' or 'instructor' to 'instructors', etc. I'll add the majority of my code to the question

Comment: (Probably unrelated, but I can't see the point of the RewriteBase directive.)  Any other rewrites in hierarchy?

Comment: My folder structure is / (root) then /api (subfolder) -  there is an .htacces in the root folder, its the same but ```RewriteBase /``` - I also tried everything without the ```RewriteBase``` in both

Comment: I guess I just have to use the routes without the trailing 's' :(

Comment: How do you access the /bands route?  http://example.com/api/bands ?

Comment: Same bug, unresolved: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/437

Comment: Thanks Progrock for pointing me to the issue in the repo. Maybe it is just something regarding my local server setup. I guess i'll give it a shot once i get everything to a producton server. I'll just develop without the 's' for now. And yes the url and route is localhost/api/bands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is the culprit here, this is not Slim-related. You have Multiviews enabled and the web server is matching the php files (bands.php). The request never reaches Slim.

To get your routes working, add this line to the beginning of your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

For further explanation on what happens, a snippet from [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.